# Lazy loaded chunks - loaded from wrong URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5

I have a working Angular5 application inside an existing Java EE application.
This Java EE app is packaged as a WAR and includes the angular sources for my app, packaged with:

ng build --prod --output-hashing none

Everything has been working for a while with all modules *preloaded*.

I am now switching to lazy-loading of modules, and with *ng serve* (localhost:4200 - local developing) everything works fine. Modules are actually lazy loaded.

In my final WAR all compiled sources are included, like main.bundle.js, 0.chunk.js ... 5.chunk.js

**Problem**

My problem is that the chunks are loaded from *http://localhost:4200/0.chunks.js* just like when working with *ng serve*.
I see the reference to *http://localhost:4200* in main.bundle.js, which explains why the chunks are loaded from there.

**Question**

*How can I achieve that the chunks are loaded from the same URL as main.bundle.js?*

I don't know in advance what the URL will be. I've played with deploy-url, but that did not work for me.

Comment: Weird, never had it lazy load from absolute urls. Must be some config issue. Build.baseHref? Can you post a link to angular-cli.json in plnkr or some?

Comment: I found the problem: In hmr.ts somehad added these lines some time ago:

`declare var __webpack_public_path__: string;
__webpack_public_path__ = 'http://localhost:4200/';`

No problem after removing that, the base-href is now used again.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `APP_BASE_HREF` Token.
As per [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF):

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/my/app'}]
})
class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Old discussion. But it seems that `APP_BASE_HREF` has no effect on the path from which chunks js files are loaded.